# Regex: Deal \r\n as normal word

Tags: regex

I'm doing a small project which can calculate the count of functions in C++ files(.cpp).

I used the following Regex as "function pattern":

```
/[a-z|A-Z]+\s*::\s*~?[a-z|A-Z]+\(.*\)/gm
```

It works for most cases, but fails when there are new line breaks in ().

```
void CXYZRScanPanel::OnPrepareScanning()
{
    //This one is ok.
}

void CXYZRScanPanel::OnPrepareScanning(int k)
{
    //This one is ok.
}

void CXYZRScanPanel::OnPrepareScanning(int k, 
                                       int j)
{
    //This one fails.
}
```

I'm thinking if there is anything "stronger" than the .* which can skip the \r\n.
Thanks for any help.

If there is no such a thing, I will probably remove all /r/n within () before doing the such.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could write the pattern using a [negated character class](https://www.regular-expressions.info/charclass.html#negated) starting with `[^` matching any char except `(` and `)` which will also match a newline.

Note that you can omit the `|` in the character class.

```
[a-zA-Z]+\s*::\s*~?[a-zA-Z]+(\([^()]*\))
```

The pattern matches:

- `[a-zA-Z]+` Match 1+ times chars a-zA-Z
- `\s*::\s*` Match `::` between optional whitespace chars
- `~?` Match an optional `~` char
- `[a-zA-Z]+` Match 1+ times chars a-zA-Z
- `(` Capture **group 1**

  - `\([^()]*\)` Optionally match any char except `(` and `)` between parenthesis
- `)` Close group 1

See a [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/IcyRJH/1)

Comment: It will take me some time to understand. But it does work! thank you so much.

Comment: And, I noticed the last function on your demo page is not recognized. Would you please change the regex to do it? I thought of this situation, but it's very rare. Thanks again.

Comment: @cheny The first pattern will match the last function, see https://regex101.com/r/IcyRJH/1 If that one is working, I can remove the second one. Is that what you mean?

Comment: Oh, I see it. Thanks again! Yes the first one is what I wanted. But I think the link in your comment above is the best, because it has the example of multiple /r/n.

Comment: @cheny Ok I have updated it with that link and removed the second pattern.